# how can two different deep learning frameworks use the same model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe

In the deep dream example using tensorflow [here](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/14_DeepDream.ipynb), the code references the inception5h model developed by google. However the original code from google [here](https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb) is using caffe, not tensorflow, probably because tensor flow did not exist then. How is it that the same model can be used by two different frameworks? The 'deploy.prototxt' distributed with the bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel lists many convolution layers but the tensor flow implementation of the same model does not reference them and seems to use many fewer layers.

If I get a pretained model without a 'deploy.prototxt' file, how can i determine how many layers the model has and how to reference them?

Comment: What do you mean by referencing a layer?

Comment: look in the prototxt file and you'll see what i mean. All the layers in the model are named there.

Comment: In Caffe, `net.forward()` returns dictionary. You can use layer name as index to get output of required layer e.g. `net.forward()["mylayer"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I get a pretrained model without a 'deploy.prototxt' file, how can i determine how many layers the model has

You can visualize your model, using `draw_net.py` script provided with caffe.